# Retrieve deleted records from the MS Dynamics 365 instance

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any direct way through which I can get the deleted records from MS Dynamics 365?
I want some REST API or fetchXML through which I can view the deleted records in an entity.

I don't want to use the audit logs method.

Answer (score 2):

Audit log is the only way to see any deleted records in Model driven app. Unless you are implementing any custom solution.